# Conditionally redirecting throw error

Tags: typescript, angular5, typescript-typings

From the subscribe I am checking the `data node`, else require to redirect to home page. but getting error.

here is my code :

```
this.sharedData.onlineBookingDatasObserver.subscribe((data:any) => {

            if( data && data.bd.cart ){
                this.cartData = data.bd.cart;
                return;
            }

            this.router.navigate(['']);

});
```

But getting error as :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'cart' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as:

```
     if(data && data.bd && data.bd.cart)
      {
        //do stuff here
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

There the error is given because **data.bd** is undefined. So you have to check wether it's there as you have done for **data**. So Modify 3rd line like below.

```
if( data && data.bd && data.bd.cart ){
```

Comment: why do you test the data as 2 times `data && data` -?